# Функция dump / dd в laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, кто - то вкурсе как изменить css функции dump в laravel ?

Черный background напрягает при выводе информации.

Либо найти где определяется функция dd в laravel, и убрать из функции die.

Чтобы dd работал без завершения скрипта.

Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция объявлена в этом файле:

> /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php

Comment: спасибо добрый человек

Answer (score 1):

Черный background напрягает при выводе информации? И это действительно так.
Поменять цвета, шрифт и др. можно в защищенном свойстве **protected $styles = array(...);** в файле **HtmlDumper.php**

Путь к файлу:
**\vendor\symfony\var-dumper\Dumper - файл HtmlDumper.php**

Вариант:

```
protected $styles = array(
        'default' => 'border:1px solid #D4D4D4; background-color:#F5F5F5; color:#E01D01; line-height:1.2em; font:14px Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, monospace; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap; position:relative; z-index:99999; word-break: normal',
        'num' => 'font-weight:bold; color:#1299DA',
        'const' => 'font-weight:bold',
        'str' => 'font-weight:bold; color:#007575',
        'note' => 'font-weight:bold; color:#1299DA',
        'ref' => 'color:#800000',
        'public' => 'color:#0000F2',
        'protected' => 'color:#0000F2',
        'private' => 'color:#0000F2',
        'meta' => 'color:#B729D9',
        'key' => 'color:#0000F2',
        'index' => 'font-weight:bold; color:#1299DA',
    );
```